# disabling mod-security cpanel

Tags: c#, php, cpanel, mod-security, mod-security2

I developed a Sync. software based-on C#.
it read some values from database and make a string as url.
then call a url with WebClient and pass url with values.
at the server,i wrote a php page that use $_GET to fetching the values,then insert them to
mysql database...
for first record,that's work,but after that my program ends with 406-Not Acceptable exception.
after some searches i know the modsecurity in the problem.and i try to disable that.
so,i add these line to .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
SecFilterInheritance Off
</IfModule>
```

but it doesn't work...
i try to solve that and i was found my cpanel is cpanel accelerated2...
so i change code to :

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
    SecFilterInheritance Off
    </IfModule>
```

but now,with this change,all of my pages doesn't work and i get error 500...
and now i like some one help me...

Answer (score 0):

The directives you are trying to use won't work in a .htaccess file, they need to be added to the VirtualHost definition for the site you want mod security disabled for and the best way to do that with cPanel is to use a separate include file.

You can edit httpd.conf directly to add the include file and then update the changes with the cPanel httpd.conf distiller `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update` . If you don't have root level access to your server your host should be able to do this for you.